# php prev/next on a resultset for navigation

Tags: php, pdo, navigation, dataset

I want to navigate through a dataset with two buttons. I want to display just one single entry each time. In theory I set the pointer to the next or previous record. But it does not work. So I tried it on another way.

For explanation: The $picklistNr has to be fix. It contains a list of articles. I want to navigate through the results be setting the LIMIT.

The query returns an array via PDO like this:

```
public function getPicklistItems($picklistNr,$pos = null){    

$sql = "SELECT pitem.*, plist.PLHkey
            FROM stpPicklistItems pitem
            RIGHT JOIN stpArtikel2Pickliste a2p
            ON (pitem.id = a2p.ArtikelID)

            LEFT JOIN stpPickliste plist
            ON (a2p.PicklistID = plist.PLHkey)

           WHERE plist.PLHkey = '{$picklistNr}'            
           LIMIT {$pos} OFFSET 1
            ";

    $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}
<?php
// Contents in my view

$pos = 0;

$picklist = $this->Picklist->getPicklistItems('60000',$pos);

if($_POST['nav'] == 'n') {
$pos += 1;
$picklist = $this->Picklist->getPicklistItems('60000',$pos);
}

if($_POST['nav'] == 'p') {
$pos -= 1;
$picklist = $this->Picklist->getPicklistItems('60000',$pos);
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="nav" value="n">
<button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="nav" value="p">
<button type="submit">Previous</button>
</form>
```

The problem with this updated code is, that I can submit the form once. The $pos goes from 0 to 1 and the output is as expected. The next article is displayed. But this works just one. If I press the button a second time, nothing happens.

If I press the p Button to decrement the $pos, the result is -1 instead of $pos-1.

Comment: You only have one row returned, `LIMIT 1`. select 3 throws output the middle one and link to the next and previous `id`s. You also are mis-using prepared statements. `$picklistNr` should be a placeholder and `$picklistNr` should then be bound. `value="n"` and/or `value="p"` will never tell you where you should be.

Comment: I have updated my code. The problem stays the same. But the approach is an other.